# Color gpx track bsaed on elevation using leaflet or plotly in R shiny

Tags: r, shiny, leaflet, plotly, polyline

I'm trying to plot a gpx track in a Shiny application such that the gpx plot color is based on the elevation (altitude) at any given point. My sample gpx files contain anywhere between 4,000 and 10,000 points (coordinate pairs). The elevation can show minimal variation (flat track near sea level) or variation upto 1600m (hiking trails).

** Desired Output **

Sample from https://iosphere.github.io/Leaflet.hotline/demo/ using plugins in Leaflet. More details here: https://github.com/iosphere/Leaflet.hotline/
There's no R code available and I don't know how to integrate plugins for leaflet in R.

[image]

** Reading Data **

```
dat <- plotKML::readGPX(my_gpx_file) # sample file link below
track <- as.data.table(dat$tracks[[1]][[1]])
track[, ele := as.numeric(ele)]
```

** With Plotly **

The `scattermapbox` option only plots markers which can be colored based on a column but the output markers are not connected by lines (expected)

```
plot_mapbox(data = track, mode = 'scattermapbox') %>%
  add_markers(x = ~lon, y = ~lat, color = ~ele, hoverinfo = 'none') %>%
  layout(
    mapbox = list(
      zoom = 10,
      center = list(lon = track[, mean(lon)], lat = track[, mean(lat)])
    )
  )
```

[image]

switching to `add_trace(..., mode = 'lines+markers')` retains the marker color from above screenshot but colors the line with a uniform standard blue. If set to `add_trace(..., mode = 'lines')` the plot disappears (i.e. does not render):

[image]

** Using Leaflet **

With a basic call using `addPolyLines` :

```
leaflet(track) %>%
  fitBounds(lng1 = min(track$lon), lat1 = min(track$lat),
            lng2 = max(track$lon), lat2 = max(track$lat)) %>%
  clearShapes() %>%
  clearControls() %>%
  addProviderTiles(
    provider = providers$Thunderforest,
    options = list(variant = 'transport',
                   apikey = my_api_key)
  ) %>%
  addPolylines(lng = ~lon,
               lat = ~lat)
```

[image]

Using `color = ~ele` in the `addPolylines` call doesn't work (plot vanishes) but the tiles remain. I've tried using `colorNumeric`, `colorRamp` as well with the same results. The call was modified to `addPolylines(..., color = ~colorFunc(ele))` where `colorFunc` could be:

```
colorFunc <- colorNumeric(
  palette = c('#000000', '#B20000') ,
  domain = track$ele
)
```

or

```
colorFunc <- colorRamp(
  colors = c('#FDFDFD', '#B20000'), 
  bias = 5, 
  interpolate = 'linear'
  )
```

`colorRamp` showed a variation in the output for different values of elevation whereas `colorNumeric` always defaulted to the high color (`#B20000`).
`colorRampPalette` worked for some folks but didn't change my output here.

I've seen several answers on SO and other forums but none of them worked out for me.

1. [Leaflet colours for polylines](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35143155/leaflet-colours-for-polylines)
2. [How to plot polylines in multiple colors in R?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42390573/how-to-plot-polylines-in-multiple-colors-in-r)
3. [Adding color to polylines in leaflet in R](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51806407/adding-color-to-polylines-in-leaflet-in-r)
4. https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/90193/color-code-a-leaflet-polyline-based-on-additional-values-e-g-altitude-speed

** Data **

sample data below (50 points only). You can download a sample file here: https://ridewithgps.com/routes/28431977

```
structure(list(lat = c(45.54214, 45.54205, 45.54183, 45.54148, 
45.54103, 45.54081, 45.54041, 45.54036, 45.5403499, 45.53998, 
45.53985, 45.53954, 45.5394, 45.53918, 45.53898, 45.53893, 45.53893, 
45.53882, 45.53882, 45.53884, 45.53888, 45.5390299, 45.53926, 
45.53937, 45.53976, 45.54013, 45.54032, 45.54045, 45.54048, 45.54055, 
45.5406199, 45.54071, 45.5409099, 45.54103, 45.54131, 45.54162, 
45.54197, 45.54247, 45.5427, 45.5428, 45.5441, 45.5443799, 45.54557, 
45.54627, 45.54639, 45.54656, 45.54667, 45.54685, 45.54706, 45.54714
), lon = c(-73.55111, -73.55079, -73.55008, -73.5489, -73.54741, 
-73.54671, -73.54546, -73.54528, -73.54524, -73.54394, -73.54346, 
-73.54244, -73.54192, -73.54115, -73.54048, -73.54029, -73.54029, 
-73.54025, -73.54025, -73.54021, -73.54013, -73.53994, -73.53964, 
-73.53954, -73.53937, -73.53905, -73.5389, -73.53877, -73.53871, 
-73.53827, -73.53814, -73.53812, -73.53824, -73.53825, -73.5381, 
-73.5378, -73.53758, -73.53713, -73.53706, -73.53701, -73.53625, 
-73.536, -73.53537, -73.53502, -73.53498, -73.5349899, -73.53504, 
-73.53528, -73.53529, -73.53527), ele = c(23.7, 23.3, 22.8, 21.9, 
21.6, 21.8, 21.9, 22.1, 22.1, 21.2, 20, 17.7, 16.6, 15.3, 14.8, 
14.8, 14.8, 14.7, 14.7, 14.7, 14.7, 14.8, 14.8, 14.8, 14.3, 13.6, 
13.4, 13.2, 13.1, 12.6, 12.5, 12.4, 12.6, 12.6, 12.4, 12.2, 12.4, 
12.3, 12.2, 12.2, 12.3, 12.4, 12.7, 12.9, 12.9, 12.9, 12.9, 13.2, 
13.2, 13.2)), row.names = c(NA, -50L), class = c("data.table", 
"data.frame"), .internal.selfref = <pointer: 0x7f91fb8096e0>)
```

Answer (score 2):

Here is my go at things...

inspiration from:
https://gist.github.com/helgasoft/799fac40f6fa2561c61cd1404521573a

```
library(plotKML)  #for reading gpx
library(dplyr)    #for setting ele to numeric
library(leaflet)
library(htmltools)
library(htmlwidgets)

#load gpx file, convert data to lat-lon-ele data.frame
mydata <- plotKML::readGPX( "./temp/19_aout_2018_-_au_complet.gpx" )$tracks[[1]][[1]] %>%
  dplyr::mutate( ele = as.numeric( ele ) )
#download the needed js-file to C:/temp (create c:/Temp first if necessairy)
download.file("https://raw.githubusercontent.com/iosphere/Leaflet.hotline/master/dist/leaflet.hotline.js", 
              'C:/Temp/leaflet.hotline.js', mode="wb")
#load the plugin
hotlinePlugin <- htmltools::htmlDependency(
  name = 'Leaflet.hotline',
  version = "0.4.0",
  src = c(file = normalizePath('C:/Temp')),
  script = "leaflet.hotline.js"
  )
#register plugin
registerPlugin <- function( map, plugin ) {
  map$dependencies <- c( map$dependencies, list( plugin ) )
  map
}
#draw leaflet
leaflet() %>% addTiles() %>%
  fitBounds( min(mydata$lon), min(mydata$lat), max(mydata$lon), max(mydata$lat) ) %>%
  registerPlugin(hotlinePlugin) %>%
  onRender("function(el, x, data) {
    data = HTMLWidgets.dataframeToD3(data);
    data = data.map(function(val) { return [val.lat, val.lon, val.ele]; });
    L.hotline(data, {min: 15, max: 70}).addTo(this);
  }", data = mydata )
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks, much appreciated! Could you add some explanation on how this works - I've got a few more parameters that I could base the plot on (min. value, color palette etc.). Also, how would this work for a shiny app?

Comment: parameters that ban be added are on the github-page you mentioned in your question..., you enter them here in the code, separated by a comma, the way I already entered `min` and `max`: `{min: 15, max: 70}`.. for a hiny app, I guess it works the same, but you'll have to put your `leaflet.hotline.js` in a data-folder insice your app, and link there...

Comment: further eplanation... not really.. I'm no leaflet expert and constructed this example based on some googling and my own limited leaflet-knowledge.

Comment: and for the shiny part: in the link in my answer, is acually a shiny app... so it should probably work just fine if you follow that example...

Comment: It works for a standalone map but doesn't work with `leafletProxy` in the Shiny `server` code..

Comment: Sorry to hear  that.  Perhaps it is better to ask a new question, building on this code.